# Numpy: strange different behavior of inplace and explicit operation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, in-place, numpy-ndarray

I want to operate on numpy arrays to use their indexing, and I want to include the 0-dimensional case. Now I came across a strange situation, where a type conversion appears, if I don't use in-place multiplication:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = 1.*np.array(1.)

In [3]: y = np.array(1.)

In [4]: y *= 1.

In [5]: x
Out[5]: 1.0

In [6]: y
Out[6]: array(1.)

In [7]: type(x)
Out[7]: numpy.float64

In [8]: type(y)
Out[8]: numpy.ndarray
```

Why is the type of x different to y? I know, that the inplace operations are differently implemented and they don't create a copy of the array, but I don't get the point, why the type is changed, if I multiply a 0d-array with a float? It works for 1d-arrays:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.array(1.)

In [3]: y = np.array([1.])

In [4]: 1.*x
Out[4]: 1.0

In [5]: 1.*y
Out[5]: array([1.])

In [7]: type(1.*x)
Out[7]: numpy.float64

In [8]: type(1.*y)
Out[8]: numpy.ndarray
```

I think, that's strange... Now I run into the following problem, where I would have to treat 0d-array separately:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.array(1.)

In [3]: y = np.array(1.)*1.

In [4]: x[x>0]
Out[4]: array([1.])

In [5]: y[y>0]
Out[5]: array([1.])

In [6]: x[x>0] = 2.

In [7]: y[y>0] = 2.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5f9c5b138fc0> in <module>()
----> 1 y[y>0] = 2.

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: I think the fundamental question here is "Why does the expression `1.0*np.array(1.0)` result in an object of type `numpy.float64` instead of `numpy.ndarray` (with shape `()`)?"

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: You are totally right!

Comment: Another odd case for you: `y=np.array(1.); z=1.; z*=y`  leaves `z` as `1.0`

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6051

Comment: An `np.float64` object and an 0d array of the same dtype share many of the same attributes - shape, dtype.  And they have many of the same methods.  This assignment restriction is the most obvious difference.

Comment: [https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5297)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5297)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately this behavior comes down to free choices made by the developer(s), and so no good explanation need necessarily exist. However, I would like to defend/explain the observed behavior as follows.

In the case of

```
y = np.array(1.)
y *= 1.
```

we create a `np.ndarray` object `y`, and then do an operation *on* it. Here, the most natural behavior is for the operation to (maybe) alter the *value* of `y`, while the type should stay the same. This is indeed what actually happens.

As an aside, note the distinction between *type* and NumPy data type (or *dtype*). Had we started out with `y = np.array(1)` (dtype of `np.int64`), the operation `y *= 1.` is now illegal as this would need to change the `dtype` in-place!

For the case `x = 1.*np.array(1.)`, let's white it out as

```
x1 = 1.
x2 = np.array(1.)
x = x1*x2
```

Here, we do not create an object and then operate *on* it. Instead we create two objects, `x1` and `x2`, and then combine them into a third object, `x`, using a *symmetric* operation (here binary multiplication). As `x1` and `x2` happen to have different (but compatible) types, the type of `x` is non-obvious: It could equally well be the type of `x1` (`float`) or the type of `x2` (`numpy.ndarray`). Surprisingly, the actual answer is neither, as the type of `x` is `np.float64`. This behavior stems from two separate choices.

#### Choice 1

**Combining a 0-dimensional array with a scalar results in a scalar, not a 0-dimensional array.** This is really the choice that trips you up. I suppose it might as well have been chosen the other way around. A global switch (e.g. `np.return_scalar = False`) would be a nice feature to have!

#### Choice 2

**Combining NumPy numeric data types with standard Python numeric types results in NumPy numeric data types.** Here, the first category include things like `np.int64`, `np.float64`, `np.complex128` (and many more), while the latter consists only of `int`, `float` and `complex` (for Python 2, also `long`). Thus, `float` times `np.float64` results in `np.float64`.

Taken together, the two choices indeed makes `x = 1.*np.array(1.)` a NumPy scalar of dtype `np.float64`.

Comment: Note: `type(np.array(1.) * np.array(1.))` retutns `np.float64`. This is because `*` calls the `np.multiply` ufunc, and ufuncs convert 0-dimensional arrays to scalars when returning.